# Python: why does this error occur in this Python console app?

Tags: python-3.x, console-application

I was developing a console application in Python and I wanted to check valid email providers ex. gmail.com.  The problem is that when I add this line;

```
def print_valid(address):
    points = 0
    count = 0
    chars = [char for char in address]
    unallowed_symbols = ["#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "/"]
    email_providers = ["@outlook", "@gmail", "@hotmail", "@yahoo"]

    # point one
    if "@" in address:
        points += 1
        
    # point two
    for letters in chars:
        if "@" in letters:
            count += 1

    if count < 1 or count > 1:
        points -= 1 
    else: 
        points += 1

    # point three
    for symbols in unallowed_symbols:
        if symbols in address:
            points -= 1
        else:
            break
    points += 1

    # point four
    for provider in email_providers:
        if provider in address:
            points += 1
        else: # this line
            points -= 1 # this line

    # check points
    if points == 4:
        return "Valid address"
    else: 
        return "Invalid address"

email = str(input("Enter email: "))
print(print_valid(email))
```

When I add those two lines and enter an invalid email, ex. @fake.com says invalid but to @gmail.com it also outputs invalid. I don't want you to correct my code. I just want to know why this error happened.

Thank you

Comment: You're going through each provider and decrementing ```points``` even if you've already encountered the actual provider.   Which would decrease the points value.  You should exit that loop once you've encountered the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decrease the `points` in `point four` for extra 3 times.

code:

```
def print_valid(address):
    points = 0
    count = 0
    chars = [char for char in address]
    unallowed_symbols = ["#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "/"]
    email_providers = ["@outlook", "@gmail", "@hotmail", "@yahoo"]

    # point one
    if "@" in address:
        points += 1
        
    # point two
    for letters in chars:
        if "@" in letters:
            count += 1

    if count < 1 or count > 1:
        points -= 1 
    else: 
        points += 1

    # point three
    for symbols in unallowed_symbols:
        if symbols in address:
            points -= 1
        else:
            break
    points += 1

    # point four
    for provider in email_providers:
        if provider in address:
            points += 1
            break
        # else: # this line
        #     points -= 1 # this line

    # check points
    if points == 4:
        return "Valid address"
    else: 
        return "Invalid address"

# email = str(input("Enter email: "))
email = "ex. @fake.com"
print(print_valid(email))
email = "@gmail.com"
print(print_valid(email))
```

result:

```
Invalid address
Valid address
```